# Generate PDF from HTML page made with Bootstrap and ChartJS in Laravel

Tags: laravel, chart.js, laravel-6, dompdf

My web app is running under Laravel 6.

In this app, I have a html page that is accessible through an URL but I also want to download this exact same page. The page is made with Bootstrap 4 and has charts using ChartJS lib.

When I try to download as PDF (thanks to Dompdf for Laravel) the exact same page, I get the following error message :

```
No block-level parent found. Not good.
```

Comment: That's a general failure to read any content from the document. Would help to see a sample of the HTML + CSS. But also note that Dompdf does not support JavaScript parsing so your chart won't render without first exporting to an image format from the client (i.e. browser).

Answer (score 1):

added in the config/dompdf.php

```
"enable_html5_parser" => true,
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using WKHTMLTOPDF and generating images corresponding to the charts before (browser side). Fastest solution for me :)